# How can I ship my vue npm library to support both Vue 2 and Vue 3,

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a Vue.js library that measures password strength.
I created the bundle for NPM with this command:

```
ue-cli-service build --target lib --name passwordMeter src/password-meter.vue
```

It works great with Vue 2.x with no problem but I get this error in the console when I use it in Vue 3

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _vm._self is undefined
```

I didn't use any features of Vue 2 that are not supported with Vue 3

The library's GitHub page:
https://github.com/miladd3/vue-simple-password-meter

Test with Vue 3: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sara-sfyqv?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Check this out : https://github.com/antfu/vue-demi

Comment: @PierreSaid I Already know about this but I want to be dependency-free cause I coded the component in a way that supports both Vue2 and Vue3.

Comment: I'm not sure that's technically feasible. Regardless, since you already used Vue 2, documentation describing how to convert to Vue 3 should give you the needed insight.

Comment: @Ouroborus So you're saying that there can't be any universal bundled npm package without using vue-demi as a dependency?


it already is ok with vue 3 the problem is bundling for npm to be used in both Vue 3 and Vue 2.

Comment: I think there probably can be a universal build, but I don't think you'd be able to use the packager to do it. (This is why I said not feasible rather than impossible. It's likely possible via hand-crafted packaging.) Your code may be cross compatible but Vue itself isn't.

Comment: hi @MiladDehghan, did u get it solved? I am having the exact problem

Comment: Same problem here. Library should be vue 2 and vue 3 compatible, but vite builds give me this error